# ¿Como abrir la configuración de seguridad para aplicaciones con acceso en versiones >= Lollipop?

Tags: java, android

actualmente estoy usando el servicio de accesibilidad, pero desde lollipop android exige ademas tener activado aplicaciones con acceso Configuración->Seguridad->Aplicaciones con acceso-> miAplicacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

Con esto puedo ir y abrir seguridad->aplicaciones con acceso.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=      ConfigurationFile.MINIMUM_VERSION_TO_MONITOR_APP_USAGE) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

//Con este metodo verifico si esta activado o no
 public  boolean AppsAcessActivate(){

```
   try {
       PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
       ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
       AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) this.getSystemService(ApplicationsAccessActivity.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
       int mode = 0;
       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= ConfigurationFile.MINIMUM_VERSION_TO_MONITOR_APP_USAGE) {
           mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
       }
       return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

   } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       return false;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Realiza un `Intent` con [ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS), aunque no puedes acceder a los detalles y funciona mínimo en API 16.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: No hay forma de averiguar si la aplicación está activada en aplicaciones con acceso ? ya que en seguridad se puede verificar si la App esta activada como administrador

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que yo recomiendo sin tener que hacer uso de código es adaptar el programa de Android Studio con las descargas de los paquetes de las versiones de Android así ya solo se desarrollara la aplicación de forma normal y sera compatible con la versión que desees: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de haber hecho esto aparecera una ventana con todas las versiones posibles que hay para android studio ya a partir de hay al crear una aplicacion solo hay que seleccionar la version que deseamos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]